# Powershell add file name to text file

Tags: powershell

I am currently writing a script that consolidates all of the contents of several text files into one file. I would like to (if possible), write into the file, the name of the file above the contents from that file.

Example:

```
Textfile1.txt

ContentContentContent
ContentContentContent

Textfile2.txt

ContentContentContent
ContentContentContent

Textfile3.txt

ContentContentContent
ContentContentContent
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you provide more details, preferably some sample code, showing how you are grabbing the list of file names and writing them out?  The answer really depends on how you are currently doing things.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, it's not too hard at all.  We get a listing of the files we want using the `Dir` command, then we pipe that into `ForEach` to run a {scriptblock}.  We'll then build a `$variable` to create the blob of text that we'll add to our existing file (Output.txt).

We can use the `$_` variable to pull out the FileName property, and then use the `Get-Content` cmdlet to grab the text of the file, giving us the fields you wanted.  We join them both with the `n NewLine character. The end result, is this:

```
dir *.txt | ForEach {
    $variable = "$($_.Name)`n$(Get-content $_.FullName)"
    Add-Content -Value $variable -Path .\Output.txt
}
```

Which gives us an output like this:

```
TextFile1.txt
ContentContentContent ContentContentContent
TextFile2.txt
ContentContentContent ContentContentContent
TextFile3.txt
ContentContentContent ContentContentContent
```

Comment: Please note that `dir` is an alias for `Get-ChildItem` and `ForEach` is an alias for `ForEach-Object`. Clarification required if the OP wants single line or multiline input from the file contents.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help everyone, you answered my questions perfectly!

Comment: @MarcClar If this answered your question ( which it does not look like it completely since you made a new one) Please mark this as accepted. You should have just asked the answerer about your issue so he could have updated the answer here.